# Ending a running transition at new hover in pure css

Tags: css, transition

I am trying to end (overwrite) a running transition in pure css. The css-code that tries to overwrite doesn't work; it isn't just ignored and I can't explain the behaviour.

Below is an example-code with 3 links each followed by 1 `div`. 3 more `div` are added afterwards just for testing.

```css
div {
  background-color: white;
  width: 50px;
  transition: all;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}
a:hover ~ div {
  width: 50px;
  color: red;
}
a:hover + div {
  width: 100px;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
```

```html
<a>link 1</a>
<div>text 1</div>
<a>link 2</a>
<div>tekst 2</div>
<a>link 3</a>
<div>tekst 3</div>
<div>tekst 4</div>
<div>tekst 5</div>
<div>tekst 6</div>
```

- At hover on a link, *only* the first-following `div` is changed in width because of the `+` selector.
- The transition-delay keeps this hover on for 1s extra.

The issue is now that when a new hover happens, I wish all hover-effects on all **following** boxes to terminate. Think of it as a menu; when hovering a new menupoint, I wish all other submenus to close and only the current one to open.

- The hope was with the `~` selector to make *all* following `div` back to normal width, and then the `a:hover + div` can expand the width of just the right one. But this doesn't work.

The `color: red` text-coloring is added for testing. Because after some testing I found out that the issue isn't the `~` selector nor the css-order, but rather the *transition*. Removing all transition lines and the result is exactly as expected, just without the delays. You can see the results here:

- [Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SteevenSpangsdorf/9v3mbn2v/12/) with the above non-working code, and
- [here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SteevenSpangsdorf/9v3mbn2v/13/) with the transition code-lines removed, where it all works (but missing the delay).

Without transition code-lines all following `div` get red text - also the three extra ones in the bottom. But *with* the transitions code-lines, they are *not* colored red - in fact only the *hovered* one is coloered red, which means that the code-lines are not entirely ignored, but doesn't work as a `~` selector anymore.

Conclusion is that the transitions interfere. I apparently can't stop a running transition and the interfering chunk of code is behaving unexpectedly and not ignored.

What is exactly the behaviour of the transitions code lines that causes this?

---

For those curious I can tell that in reality on the project I'm working on the original width before hover is 0. Therefore this solution will work:

```
a:hover ~ div {
  display:none;
}
```

Instead of trying to reset the width, I remove the width and all is good. I am rather asking the question above to understand, what the issue is.

Comment: Please look in this https://jsfiddle.net/9v3mbn2v/14/

Comment: @Draval There is no delay effect. (Testing in Firefox and Edge.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, just add `transition: none` to your `a:hover ~ div`

https://jsfiddle.net/e3p97ewj/

Comment: Well, isn't that just perfect. Thank you, very much. but may I ask if you know what is happening above? Why is the `a:hover ~ div` not working on the bottom `div` without this?